# Drag & Drop Gridview Rows

Tags: asp.net

I have requirement like client can able to Drag and drop and change the position of  rows in Gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be able to accomplish that with JQuery's Sortable plugin: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Since the grid renders a table element, you should be able target it this way: http://devblog.foliotek.com/2009/07/23/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/

HTH.